# Searching an arraylist for the index of an object with a specific value

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm writing a program to take and organize class info, including the students in a class, recorded by ID and Grade. I'm able to add the students as desired, and they print as desired (so I know the entries are correct), but when I go to search for a student, the search method is only able to find the last entered student ID. Why is my search function breaking down?

The search function:

```
public static int studentFinder(ClassSection classOne) {
      int studentIndex = 0;
      boolean searchAgain = false;
      boolean correctStudent = false;
     do {
      studentIndex = idFinder(classOne);
        if (studentIndex == -1) {
            System.out.println("That student was not found in the class");
            System.out.println("Would you like to search again?");
                searchAgain = yesNoBool();
        } else {
            System.out.println("You have selected student ID# " +classOne.getStudentIDByIndex(studentIndex));
                System.out.println("Is this correct?");
                    correctStudent = yesNoBool();
                        if (!correctStudent) {
                            System.out.println("Would you like to search again?");
                                searchAgain = yesNoBool();
                        }
        }
     } while(searchAgain);
     return studentIndex;
  }
```

ID Finder module:

```
public static int idFinder(ClassSection classOne) {
      int studentID = 0;
      String intString = "a Student ID to search for:";
      int studentIndex = 0;
      System.out.println("Please enter a Student ID to search for:");
        studentID = intChecker(intString);
      for (int i = 0; i < classOne.students.size(); i++) {
          int studentIdTest = classOne.students.get(i).getStudentID();
            if (studentIdTest == studentID) {
                studentIndex = i;
            } else if (studentIdTest != studentID){
                studentIndex = -1;
            }
      }
        return studentIndex;
  }
```

The ClassSection class:

```
import java.util.*;


public class ClassSection {
    //instance variables
     protected int crnNum = 0;
     protected String deptCode = "null";
     protected int courseNum = 0;
     protected String instructMode = "null";
     protected String meetingDays = "null";
     protected String meetingTimesStart = "null";
     protected String meetingTimesEnd = "null";
     protected int classCapacity = 0;
     protected int classEnrollment = 0;
     protected int instructorID = 0;
     protected ArrayList<StudentEnrollee> students = new ArrayList<StudentEnrollee>();

    //constructors
        public ClassSection(int crnNum, String deptCode, int courseNum, String instructMode, String meetingDays,
                String meetingTimesStart, String meetingTimesEnd, int classCapacity, int classEnrollment,
                int instructorID) {
            super();
            this.crnNum = crnNum;
            this.deptCode = deptCode;
            this.courseNum = courseNum;
            this.instructMode = instructMode;
            this.meetingDays = meetingDays;
            this.meetingTimesStart = meetingTimesStart;
            this.meetingTimesEnd = meetingTimesEnd;
            this.classCapacity = classCapacity;
            this.classEnrollment = classEnrollment;
            this.instructorID = instructorID;
        }


    public ClassSection() {
        super();
        this.crnNum = 0;
        this.deptCode = "";
        this.courseNum = 0;
        this.instructMode = "";
        this.meetingDays = "";
        this.meetingTimesStart = "";
        this.meetingTimesEnd = "";
        this.classCapacity = 0;
        this.classEnrollment = 0;
        this.instructorID = 0;
    }



    //getters and setters
        public void getStudents() {
            this.students.forEach(System.out::println);
        }

        public int getStudentIDByIndex(int index) {
            return this.students.get(index).getStudentID();
        }

        public void addStudent(StudentEnrollee student) {
            this.students.add(student);
        }

        public void removeStudent(int removalIndex) {
            this.students.remove(removalIndex);
        }

        public void changeAddStudentGrade(int studentIndex, int studentGrade) {
            this.students.get(studentIndex).setStudentGrade(studentGrade);
        }

        public int getCrnNum() {
            return crnNum;
        }

        public void setCrnNum(int crnNum) {
            this.crnNum = crnNum;
        }
        public String getDeptCode() {
            return deptCode;
        }
        public void setDeptCode(String deptCode) {
            this.deptCode = deptCode;
        }
        public int getCourseNum() {
            return courseNum;
        }
        public void setCourseNum(int courseNum) {
            this.courseNum = courseNum;
        }
        public String getInstructMode() {
            return instructMode;
        }
        public void setInstructMode(String instructMode) {
            this.instructMode = instructMode;
        }
        public String getMeetingDays() {
            return meetingDays;
        }
        public void setMeetingDays(String meetingDays) {
            this.meetingDays = meetingDays;
        }

        public String getMeetingTimesStart() {
            return meetingTimesStart;
        }


        public void setMeetingTimesStart(String meetingTimesStart) {
            this.meetingTimesStart = meetingTimesStart;
        }


        public String getMeetingTimesEnd() {
            return meetingTimesEnd;
        }

        public void setMeetingTimesEnd(String meetingTimesEnd) {
            this.meetingTimesEnd = meetingTimesEnd;
        }

        public int getClassCapacity() {
            return classCapacity;
        }
        public void setClassCapacity(int classCapacity) {
            this.classCapacity = classCapacity;
        }
        public int getClassEnrollment() {
            return classEnrollment;
        }
        public void setClassEnrollment(int classEnrollment) {
            this.classEnrollment = classEnrollment;
        }
        public int getInstructorID() {
            return instructorID;
        }
        public void setInstructorID(int instructorID) {
            this.instructorID = instructorID;
        }




        //mutators
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Crn Number: %20s \nDept Code: %20s \nInstruction Mode: %20s"
                    + " \nCourse Number: %20s \nClass Capacity: %20s \nClass Enrollment: %20s"
                    + " \nMeeting Days: %20s \nMeeting Times: %8$20s - %9$2s \nInstructor ID: %10$20s \n" + Arrays.toString(students.toArray()).replace("[", "").replace(", S","S").replace("]", "").trim(), 
                    crnNum, deptCode, instructMode, courseNum, classCapacity, classEnrollment, meetingDays,
                    meetingTimesStart, meetingTimesEnd, instructorID);
        }



}
```

The student enrollee class (where the objects in the arraylist are from):

```
public class StudentEnrollee {
    protected int studentID = 0;
    protected int studentGrade = 0;




    public StudentEnrollee() {
        super();
        studentID = 0;
        studentGrade = 0;
    }

    public StudentEnrollee(int studentID, int studentGrade) {
        super();
        this.studentID = studentID;
        this.studentGrade = studentGrade;
    }

    //setters & getters
    public int getStudentID() {
        return studentID;
    }
    public void setStudentID(int studentID) {
        this.studentID = studentID;
    }
    public int getStudentGrade() {
        return studentGrade;
    }
    public void setStudentGrade(int studentGrade) {
        this.studentGrade = studentGrade;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Student ID: %20s  \nStudent Grade: %20s \n", studentID, studentGrade);
    } 



}
```

The intchecker and yesNoBool methods are just error checking and confirmation functions, but here they are just in case:

```
  public static int intChecker(String object) {
    boolean correctInput = false;
    int userInput = 0;

    while (!correctInput) {
        try {
            userInput = scanner.nextInt();
            correctInput = true;
        } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("I'm sorry, that doesn't seem to be a number");
            System.out.println("Please enter " +object);
            scanner.next();
        } 
    }

    return userInput;
}


  public static boolean yesNoBool() {
      String yesNo = "";
      boolean yesNoBool = false;
      System.out.println("Please enter Y/N");
        yesNo = scanner.next();
      while ((!yesNo.equalsIgnoreCase("n") && !yesNo.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))){
            System.out.println("I'm sorry, please enter Y/N");
                yesNo = scanner.next();
        } 
      if (yesNo.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
          yesNoBool = true;
      } else if (yesNo.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
          yesNoBool = false;
      }


      return yesNoBool; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you found the match you have to break the loop, otherwise `studentIndex` gets overwritten for rest of the records for which loop iterating. Also you don't need `if(studentIdTest != studentID)` just else is also work same.

Add Break in loop in idFinder method as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < classOne.students.size(); i++) {
      int studentIdTest = classOne.students.get(i).getStudentID();
        if (studentIdTest == studentID) {
            studentIndex = i;
            break;
        } else{
            studentIndex = -1;
        }
  }
```

Suggestion: you can intialize `studentIndex` with -1 instead of setting it in each iteration where match not found.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: This did it! Thank you!

Comment: @AaronC.Most welcome. Please upvote the answer if it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

In your `idFinder` method, you continue to search for the id even when you find it. In the `for` loop, you need to stop when you find the id.

Modify your for loop to:

```
public static int idFinder(ClassSection classOne) {
  String intString = "a Student ID to search for:";
  int studentIndex = -1; // Initialize the studentIndex to a negative value since 0 is a valid index
  System.out.println("Please enter a Student ID to search for:");

  int studentID = intChecker(intString);

  for (int i = 0; i < classOne.students.size(); i++) {
      int studentIdTest = classOne.students.get(i).getStudentID();
      if (studentIdTest == studentID) {
          studentIndex = i;
          break;
      }
   }
  return studentIndex;
}
```